# In Thunderbird, how to prevent users from creating new mail accounts?

Tags: windows-7, email, security, thunderbird, imap

I have just setup our company e-mail with a popular online e-mail provider. E-mails will be retrieved from the online server via Thunderbird installed on Windows 7 PC's. I wish to exercise administrative control such that Thunderbird will only connect to the particular account with the particular online e-mail provider I originally set it up with.

Which is to say, I want to prevent users from accessing their personal e-mail (e.g. Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc.) by simply creating new accounts on Thunderbird.

Is this possible? How to do it? Users are currently non-admin users with program access restrictions enforced via parental controls.

Comment: Mozilla has group policy templates have you tried look at the group policies in that template to see if there is something that woud prevent users from linking other email accounts?

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox and Thunderbird, you can [lock preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences) with the `mozilla.cfg` file.

In Windows, it allows you to set preferences on a machine level (instead of the usual user level).  Assuming the users don't have local administrator rights, they won't be able to modify any preferences that are locked this way.

I took a quick look at Thunderbird's `about:config` and found `mail.accountmanager.accounts` which you could simply lock to `account1`.  You will have to play around a bit and see what works in your specific environment.